# How to UPDATE mysql using a python input

Tags: python, syntax-error, mysql-python

I'm trying to do a simple program to work as a contact_book, but I can't get through an error when I try to update a row.
Here's the code:

```
oque = input("Digite que informação você gostaria de mudar: 'nome', 'numero', 'endereço'. Escreva 
exatamente como digitado nessa frase. ")
para = input("Digite a informação que deseja inserir  no lugar da informação anterior: ")
index = input("Digite o 'index_num do contato. Se não lembrar, consulte o contato. ")

editar = (oque, para, index,)
sql = "UPDATE contato SET %s = %s WHERE index_num = %s"

my_cursor.execute(sql, editar,)

my_database.commit()

print("Pronto!")
```

This same syntax of putting together all the inputs in a variable and then commiting worked to INSERT contacts, but when updating I'm getting the error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check 
the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '''nome'' = 
''Ivone'' WHERE index_num = ''2''' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the field name as part of the query before executing:

```
editar = (para, index,)
```

and then:

```
sql = "UPDATE contato SET %s = %%s WHERE index_num = %%s" % (oque)
```

or

````
sql = "UPDATE contato SET {} = %s WHERE index_num = %s".format(oque)```
````

or (python 3.6+)

```
sql = f"UPDATE contato SET {oque} = %s WHERE index_num = %s"
```

Then:

```
my_cursor.execute(sql, editar)
```

Comment: Great! Please mark my answer as "accepted" if you like it.